# Gett a list of related data with maximum length

Tags: c#

I have several lists in C#, for example:

```
list1={1,2,3}
list2={2,3}
list3={3,4}
list4={3,5}
list5={5,6}
list6={7,8}
list7={7,9}
```

Each data in one list is treated as related to other data in the same list.
The results I want to get two lists each of which has the maximum number of related data:

```
list_1={1,2,3,4,5,6}
list_2={7,8,9}
```

I wonder is there any simple method to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I don't understand what's causing the values to be in one list over another, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

An idea would be to create a class that contains each one of your list, and a collection of the lists it is related to, and map them out. Here is my solution: (With comments explaining)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Initial Data
    var lists = new List<RelatedList>
    {
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {1, 2, 3}),
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {2, 3}),
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {3, 4}),
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {3, 5}),
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {5, 6}),
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {7, 8}),
        new RelatedList(new List<int> {7, 9})
    };

    //Find "links" between the data
    foreach (var list in lists) 
        foreach (var other in lists) 
            foreach (var element in other.Data) 
                if (!list.RelatedLists.Contains(other) && list.Data.Contains(element))
                    list.RelatedLists.Add(other);

    var results = new List<List<int>>();
    results.Add(new List<int>());

    //Process these links into lists of the linked data
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
    {
        var list = lists[i];
        if (i == 0)
            results[results.Count - 1].AddRange(list.Data);
        else
        {
            var prev = lists[i - 1];
            if (!list.RelatedLists.Contains(prev)) //If this list is not related to anything further
            {
                results.Add(new List<int>());
                results[results.Count - 1].AddRange(list.Data);
            }
            else
                results[results.Count - 1].AddRange(list.Data);
        }
    }

    //Remove repeated values
    for (var j = 0; j < results.Count; j++)
    {
        results[j] = results[j].Distinct().ToList();
    }

    //Print them out! You may use the data of `results` 
    for (var i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        var result = results[i];
        Console.WriteLine("List {0}:", (i + 1));
        foreach (var element in result)
            Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class RelatedList
{
    public List<int> Data { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedList> RelatedLists { get; set; }

    public RelatedList(List<int> data)
    {
        RelatedLists = new List<RelatedList>();
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Which will return:

```
List 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
List 2
7
8
9
```

Comment: since OP hasn't responded can you?  What is it that's causing relationship between the lists? or rather why the specific values are in the two lists when given the sample data.

Comment: @Kritner If I understand the question correctly, each initial list is "linked" to another by having numbers in common. For example, list one has `2` and `3` in common with list 2, which has `3` in common with list 3, etc etc, until you get to list 5 and 6 where there are no numbers in common. The program will print out the "links" between them, until it breaks, and starts a new "link".